# Properly override ModelForm's form fields with keeping the **kwargs from the model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've a situation as bellow:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field 1 = models.CharField(kwarg1 = value1, kwarg2 = value2, ...)

class MyCustomCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, mandatarg1, ckwarg1 = cdefault1, ...):
       ...
    ...

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', ...]

    field1 = MyCustomCharField(mandatvalue1, ckwarg1 = cvalue1, ...)
```

---

The issue is: in my form I loose the `kwarg1 = default1, kwarg2 = default2, ...`, that can for example be `help_text="blablabla"` and `max_length=255`.

Do somebody imagine a proper way to keep this default arguments ?

---

I tried:

```
field1 = MyModel._meta.get_field('field1').formfield(form_class=MyCustomCharField, ckwarg1 = cvalue1)
```

It works perfectly, but I cannot pass the mandatvalue1 attribute, so I cannot do what I need !

---

And also

```
field1 = MyCustomCharField(mandatvalue1, ckwarg1 = cvalue1, ..., **MyModel._meta.get_field('field1').__dict__)
```

But here I got too many keys in my dict, and Django crashes..

---

Finally, I could do:

```
field1 = MyCustomCharField(mandatvalue1, ckwarg1 = cvalue1, ..., help_text = MyModel._meta.get_field('field1').help_text, ...)
```

But I've many values to copy like it, and it's hardly maintainable.. Any idea ? I'm a bit maniac, so I'd really looove a clean way of doing it (if it's not too much)

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Is the `help_text` not showing up in your template?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**kwargs` to capture and pass through all keyword arguments that you don't specify directly. `kwargs` can be anything, but convention is to use that name. It would look as follows:

```
def __init__(self, mandatarg1, ckwarg1=cdefault1, **kwargs)
    # do something
    super(MyCustomCharField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    # do something else
```

Due to the double asteriks `**`, all keyword arguments that are not specifically defined will be packed in a `dict` object called `kwargs`. By passing `**kwargs` to the call to super, these values are unpacked again before the super's `__init__` function is called with these keyword arguments.

E.g. you can call the following:

```
field1 = MyCustomCharField(mandatvalue1, max_length=255, ckwarg1 = cvalue1)
```

`kwargs` will then look like this:

```
kwargs = {'max_length': 255}
```

And python will handle the call to super as if you had called:

```
super(MyCustomCharField, self).__init__(max_length=255)
```

The same can be done for positional arguments with a single asteriks, convention is to do this with `*args`. `args` will be a tuple of the positional arguments, consistent with the order in which the arguments were passed. `*args` and `**kwargs` have to be the last arguments defined in a function definition. You should be careful with `*args`, though: always remember that in a function definition there is no difference in positional arguments and keyword arguments. So if you were to extend the `MultiValueField` class, and you want to pass the fields as a positional argument, you have to treat every single argument in you subclass's `__init__` method as a positional argument. So:

```
class MyCustomMultiValueField(forms.MultiValueField):
    def __init__(customarg1, customarg2=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        super(MyCustomMultiValueField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# this won't work, as now customargs2 is (BooleanField(), DateField()), instead of fields
MyCustomMultiValueField(1, (BooleanField(), DateField()))

# you can still pass fields as a keyword argument
MyCustomMultiValueField(1, fields=(BooleanField(), DateField()))
```

If you only want to specify keyword arguments, or if you want to specify positional arguments after the super's positional arguments, a common way to do that is to only specify `*args` and `**kwargs` as the arguments:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    keywordarg1 = kwargs.pop('keyword1', None)
    mandatorykeywordarg2 = kwargs.pop('keyword2')
    if len(args) == 2:
        # because tuples are immutable
        args = list(args)
        positionalargumentafterfields = args.pop(1)
    super(MyCustomMultiValueField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # *args also works with a list
```

A common use-case for this is when you want to specify extra arguments, while some other code relies on the positional arguments of the base class to create your subclass. Django models and forms are examples where you'd want to do this to prevent breaking the code.

Documentation on [arguments in function definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions).

Comment: My issue is still to retrieve the default arguments generated by Django's modelfield to inject them in my overrided field. I know the ways of doing it if I got them, but I've not idea of how to retrieve them

Comment: `super(MyCustomCharField, self).__init__(**kwargs)` will take care of that. It will call the `CharField`'s (your class's superclass) `__init__()` method with all keyword arguments that you don't specifically use, and that method will handle all the default functionality like specifying the max length and help text of the field.